# XCB event loop not getting any events

Tags: x11, xcb

I am making an addon in Firefox, so I have a ChromeWorker - which is a privileged WebWorker. This is just a thread other then the mainthread.

In here I have no code but this (modified to make it look like not js-ctypes [which is the language for addons])

On startup I run this code, `conn` is a global variable:

```
conn = xcb_connect(null, null);
```

Then I run this in a 200ms interval:

```
evt = xcb_poll_for_event(conn);
console.log('evt:', evt);

if (!evt.isNull()) {
    console.log('good got an event!!');
    ostypes.API('free')(evt);
}
```

However `evt` is always `null`, I am never getting any events. My goal is to get all events on the system.

Anyone know what can cause something so simple to not work?

I have tried

```
xcb_change_window_attributes (conn, screens.data->root, XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK, values);
```

But this didn't fix it :(

The only way I can get it to work is by doing `xcb_create_window` `xcb_map_window`  but then I get ONLY the events that happen in this created window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't just magically get all events by opening a connection. There's only very few messages *any* client will receive, such as client messages, most others will only be sent to a client if it explicitly registered itself to receive them.

And yes, that means you have to register them on each and every window, which involves both crawling the tree and listening for windows being created, mapped, unmapped and destroyed and registering on them as well.

However, I would reconsider whether

> My goal is to get all events on the system.

isn't an A-B problem. *Why* do you "need" all events? What do you actually want to do?

Comment: Thanks very much Ingo for your reply I'm still struggling with this, I try to troubleshoot on and off. From a spawned thread (non main-thread), I am trying to create a global hotkey. I created a screenshot tool - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nativeshot/ - its an addon for firefox. It uses js-ctypes to use native methods. People are requesting I allow an option for users set their "PrtScn" key to be the global hotkey to trigger my screenshot. So I'm strugglign with that.

Comment: To do that all you need to do is grab the key on the root window via xcb_grab_key. Of course you can only do that if no other application grabbed the key, see the documentation for that (and perhaps the Xlib equivalent, XGrabKey).

Comment: Addendum: if you want it to work without grabbing the key, you could use the Xinput2 extension, which is a bit more work and less straight-forward. But generally speaking, xcb_grab_key should suffice. That's also how window managers usually do it, for example.

Comment: Thanks very much I'll keep trying at it, i tried the xcb_grab_key but it wouldnt work I have no idea why :(

Comment: Hey @Ingo I tried it here - https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/blob/master/modules/hotkey/HotkeyWorker.js#L376-L459 but im not getting any events :( I get no errors I have no idea why it wont grab :(

Comment: Ah figured this one out! I was using `XCB_ANY_KEY` and this constant works on Debian but not on Ubuntu, which is what I was using to test. I swithced that up to use num lock, caps lock etc and now it works! :)  https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/blob/master/modules/hotkey/HotkeyWorker.js#L347-L349 that was very very crazy i had no idea the `XCB_MOD_MASK_ANY` constant didnt work on Ubuntu - https://github.com/Noitidart/System-Hotkey/blob/master/modules/hotkey/HotkeyWorker.js#L434